# Material only assigning to part of object, not all of it

Tags: texturing, materials, faces

EDIT: I've since discovered that the issued stemmed from the fact that the light wasn't shining on the black areas. Change it to hemi and the problem is fixed.

I'm new to blender, but I have a grasp on the basic functions. Supposedly. I've gone through an excellent course on it, but I'm still a bit lost in the area of materials and textures.

I am currently trying to texture a roof of a hut. Despite the fact that I've selected the whole roof in edit mode and assigned the material with the texture on it, only part of the roof gains the texture - the top.

[image]

**Note:** The top of the roof is tecturing properly: it looks solid because I'm in material view, not render. That's not the problem. The problem is that the texture is not assigning to the whole of the roof. Not the black edges of the roof, and the underside (if you open the project linked below). Those areas need to have the texture.

Why is this? I've tried to assign the material to the whole object multiple times, even selecting only one or two faces that were not affected. I can't tell if the material is ignoring the faces, the texture is, or both are (since the material looks no different from the rest of the hut for some reason - a way to tell that would be nice if I'm missing it).

I want the texture on the top of the roof like it is, but also on the sides and underside, which you cannot see in the picture. The roof is a single object, separate from the rest of the house.

[File to download.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BychXncNFzyCTzJnRmZrRjRHcFU/view?usp=sharing)

[Folder to download, including texture.](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0BychXncNFzyCRHhvUkpSNU9KUWc?usp=sharing)

What I've tried/checked:

- All normals are facing the correct way. This is the first thing I checked.
- I'm in Blender Render, not Cycles Render (I did some research and that was mentioned).
- The material/texture does work. It's on the top of the roof, after all.
- I have no way to confirm that the material is assigned to the whole object, though I don't know why it wouldn't be. I assigned it multiple times. I even deleted it and started over with the whole roof selected (ctrl+A).

Comment: Could you provide a .blend file to be able to help you?

Comment: @Tak I've edited in a link in my question.

Comment: If you have solved your question you should add an answer using the answer section below and [accept](http://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) your own answer, not edit your original question.

Comment: Check your UV map. I supect some of the faces are not mapped correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the diffuse color as shown below for all the parts you want to have the same material. So I added new material for the other parts as well and set the diffuse color to be the same as shown below:

[image]

The updated .blend file can be found here: [image]

Comment: I think you might have misunderstood my question. I've edited it to clarify; see the 'note.' I want the texture to be on all of the roof, including the sides and underside. Not just the top. The top already works fine if I look at it in render mode.

Comment: @ThomasMyron answer updated with screenshots and an updated .blend file. Please accept and upvote the answer if it was helpful.

Comment: I think I need to go and learn more about materials and textures. Your file has the material on all the faces, which is great, but I can't change the color (it's like the material won't re-apply), and I still can't get any kind of texture to show up anywhere. Thank you for your time; I'll edit the OP if I find out what I was doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You need to unwrap your mesh to your texture - select all the faces in edit mode and press 'U' to unwrap, and choose your preferred method.To test, I set my view to Top from the numpad ) and [image]used 'U, Project from View" and loaded my own image since yours wasn't packed in file.

You still need to edit your mesh to include a seam. I chose the vertex loop around the bottom edge of the roof, and then also (in edge select mode) the edges that were vertical tha tconnect the top to the bottom of the roof, and pressed ctrl-E and choose 'mark seams'. Then with all the faces selected, I pressed 'U' for unwrap and then scaled the whole island up in the UV Image Editor to set the scale for the texture against the uvs. The image texture then sits on all the faces, and since it is a tiling texture it works pretty well now. [image: unwrap to image texture]

Comment: I think you might have misunderstood my question. I've edited it to clarify; see the 'note.' I want the texture to be on all of the roof, including the sides and underside. Not just the top. The top already works fine if I look at it in render mode.

Comment: No, I just pointed out that you didn't unwrap your mesh. You will need to do that to get an image texture to map by UV as the default mapping. If you want to use generated coordinates instead, you might have a difficult time getting it to line up. Select all of the faces and Smart Unwrap and that will get you an image on all faces - but the best thing to do is to unwrap the roof from the top view, and then use the other views to unwrap the sides, etc.

Comment: Well I think one problem is that I've never come across 'unwrapping' before. I don't know what it is. I was under the impression I just assigned a material to faces, and then assigned a texture to the material. Is there another step in there?

Comment: Yes, you need to tell the mesh how to line up on that image per face, so you Unwrap it with the U key either all faces at once or sections at a time, and line them up in the UV/Image Editor to coincide with the pixels of the image texture. Procedural textures do not need the UV mapping, but images really do if they are going to be used in the viewport.

Comment: I guess I'm confused why I can see it on the top just fine then, when I'm in Render view. When I unwrap it, the picture zooms in a lot more... I liked it unzoomed. It was the perfect size.

Comment: Get a new file up with the example texture you want to use packed internally so we can see what you are seeing.

Comment: I've added a folder with the file and the texture. Hopefully it's shared correctly... It looks exactly like Tak's picture below, except it is a texture and not just a material. You can see how it isn't on the sides.